# Python and directory tree

Tags: python, python-unittest, pythonpath

I have the following directory tree

```
project
├── src
│   ├── module1
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── Object1.py
│   └── module2
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── Object2.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── module1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── test_Object1.py
    │   └── test_Object1.pyc
    ├── module2
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── test_Object2.py
    │   └── test_Object2.pyc
    └── run_tests.py
```

I have openned project in my PyCharm and set src as Source root. I want to find a way on how to place my tests. I want them to be under test folder, inside the same folder the as in src and the test file will start with test_ and the name of the file I want to test. for example inside Object2 I have created and Object2 class

```
class Object2():

    def add(self, x, y):
        return x+y


    def subtract(self, x, y):
        return x-y
```

and inside test_Object2.py

```
from module2.Object2 import Object2

import unittest

class TestObject2(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_adding_two_numbers(self):
        testing_object = Object2()
        self.assertEqual(4, testing_object.add(2, 2))
```

I navigate on project and run

```
python -m unittest discover
```

and I get the following error:

```
    ERROR: tests.module2.test_Object2 (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests.module2.test_Object2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 254, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 232, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/avlahop/development/testing/tests/module2/test_Object2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module2.Object2 import Object2
ImportError: No module named module2.Object2


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

PyCharm doesn't raise any error on the import. How do I set up path in a good way when creating a project? I want run_script to contain code that runs all tests that will be contained inside tests folder. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you found the soulution for this?